# WooCommerce – Gravity Forms Product Add-Ons – Exclude selected options Total from Cart Total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I need the Total of the GF Product Add-Ons options to be **excluded** from the Cart Total.

My product which I am selling is $100. I need the Cart Total to only be $100 + Taxes. I don't want the Options Total to be included in it. It is okay to display it in the Cart item description. The totals for these options are monthly recurring and paid offline by the customer so I don't need them to pay for it upfront.

Source Code for plugin: [WooCommerce - Gravity Forms Product Add-Ons](https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-gravityforms-product-addonsclass)

Code below is from "gravityforms-product-addons-cart.php" found within the plugin. I don't know where to start with what I need done.

```
class WC_GFPA_Cart {

private static $instance;

public static function register() {
    if ( self::$instance == null ) {
        self::$instance = new WC_GFPA_Cart;
    }
}

private function __construct() {
    // Filters for cart actions

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', array( $this, 'add_cart_item_data' ), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', array( $this, 'get_cart_item_from_session' ), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', array( $this, 'get_item_data' ), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', array( $this, 'add_cart_item' ), 10, 1 );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', array( $this, 'order_item_meta' ), 10, 3 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', array( $this, 'add_to_cart_validation' ), 99, 3 );

    //Order Again
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_again_cart_item_data', array(
        $this,
        'on_get_order_again_cart_item_data'
    ), 10, 3 );
}

//Helper function, used when an item is added to the cart as well as when an item is restored from session.
public function add_cart_item( $cart_item ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Adjust price if required based on the gravity form data
    if ( isset( $cart_item['_gravity_form_lead'] ) && isset( $cart_item['_gravity_form_data'] ) ) {
        //Gravity forms generates errors and warnings.  To prevent these from conflicting with other things, we are going to disable warnings and errors.
        $err_level = error_reporting();
        error_reporting( 0 );

        $gravity_form_data = $cart_item['_gravity_form_data'];
        $form_meta         = RGFormsModel::get_form_meta( $gravity_form_data['id'] );

        if ( empty( $form_meta ) ) {
            $_product = $cart_item['data'];
            $woocommerce->add_error( $_product->get_title() . __( ' is invalid.  Please remove and try readding to the cart', 'wc_gf_addons' ) );

            return $cart_item;
        }

        $lead = $cart_item['_gravity_form_lead'];

        $products = array();
        $total    = 0;

        $lead['id'] = uniqid() . time() . rand();

        $products = $this->get_product_fields( $form_meta, $lead );
        if ( ! empty( $products["products"] ) ) {

            foreach ( $products["products"] as $product ) {
                $price = GFCommon::to_number( $product["price"] );
                if ( is_array( rgar( $product, "options" ) ) ) {
                    $count = sizeof( $product["options"] );
                    $index = 1;
                    foreach ( $product["options"] as $option ) {
                        $price += GFCommon::to_number( $option["price"] );
                        $class = $index == $count ? " class='lastitem'" : "";
                        $index ++;
                    }
                }
                $subtotal = floatval( $product["quantity"] ) * $price;
                $total += $subtotal;
            }

            $total += floatval( $products["shipping"]["price"] );
        }

        $cart_item['data']->adjust_price( $total );
        $cart_item['_gform_total'] = $total;
        error_reporting( $err_level );
    }


    return $cart_item;
}

//When the item is being added to the cart.
public function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_meta, $product_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['gform_old_submit'] ) ) {
        return $cart_item_meta;
    }

    if ( isset( $cart_item_meta['_gravity_form_data'] ) && isset( $cart_item_meta['_gravity_form_lead'] ) ) {
        return $cart_item_meta;
    }

    $gravity_form_data                    = wc_gfpa()->get_gravity_form_data( $product_id );
    $cart_item_meta['_gravity_form_data'] = $gravity_form_data;

    if ( $gravity_form_data && is_array( $gravity_form_data ) && isset( $gravity_form_data['id'] ) && intval( $gravity_form_data['id'] ) > 0 ) {

        $form_id   = $gravity_form_data['id'];
        $form_meta = RGFormsModel::get_form_meta( $form_id );
        $form_meta = gf_apply_filters( array( 'gform_pre_render', $form_id ), $form_meta );

        //Gravity forms generates errors and warnings.  To prevent these from conflicting with other things, we are going to disable warnings and errors.
        $err_level = error_reporting();
        error_reporting( 0 );

        //MUST disable notifications manually.
        add_filter( 'gform_disable_user_notification_' . $form_id, array( $this, 'disable_notifications' ), 10, 3 );
        add_filter( 'gform_disable_admin_notification_' . $form_id, array(
            $this,
            'disable_notifications'
        ), 10, 3 );
        add_filter( 'gform_disable_notification_' . $form_id, array( $this, 'disable_notifications' ), 10, 3 );

        add_filter( "gform_confirmation_" . $form_id, array( $this, "disable_confirmation" ), 10, 4 );

        if ( empty( $form_meta ) ) {
            return $cart_item_meta;
        }

        GFFormDisplay::$submission[ $form_id ] = null;
        require_once( GFCommon::get_base_path() . "/form_display.php" );
        $_POST['gform_submit'] = $_POST['gform_old_submit'];
        GFFormDisplay::process_form( $form_id );
        $_POST['gform_old_submit'] = $_POST['gform_submit'];
        unset( $_POST['gform_submit'] );

        $lead                                 = GFFormDisplay::$submission[ $form_id ]['lead'];
        $cart_item_meta['_gravity_form_lead'] = array(
            'form_id'    => $form_id,
            'source_url' => $lead['source_url'],
            'ip'         => $lead['ip']
        );

        foreach ( $form_meta['fields'] as $field ) {
            if ( isset( $field['displayOnly'] ) && $field['displayOnly'] ) {
                continue;
            }

            $value = $this->get_lead_field_value( $lead, $field );


            $inputs = $field instanceof GF_Field ? $field->get_entry_inputs() : rgar( $field, 'inputs' );
            if ( is_array( $inputs ) ) {
                //making sure values submitted are sent in the value even if
                //there isn't an input associated with it
                $lead_field_keys = array_keys( $lead );
                natsort( $lead_field_keys );
                foreach ( $lead_field_keys as $input_id ) {
                    if ( is_numeric( $input_id ) && absint( $input_id ) == absint( $field->id ) ) {
                        $cart_item_meta['_gravity_form_lead'][ strval( $input_id ) ] = $value[ strval( $input_id ) ];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $cart_item_meta['_gravity_form_lead'][ strval( $field['id'] ) ] = $value;
            }
        }

        if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gravityforms_delete_entries', true ) ) {
            $this->delete_entry( $lead );
        }

        error_reporting( $err_level );
    }

    return $cart_item_meta;
}

public function get_cart_item_from_session( $cart_item, $values ) {

    if ( isset( $values['_gravity_form_data'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['_gravity_form_data'] = $values['_gravity_form_data'];
    }

    if ( isset( $values['_gravity_form_lead'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['_gravity_form_lead'] = $values['_gravity_form_lead'];
    }

    if ( isset( $cart_item['_gravity_form_lead'] ) && isset( $cart_item['_gravity_form_data'] ) ) {
        $this->add_cart_item( $cart_item );
    }

    return $cart_item;
}

public function get_item_data( $other_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item['_gravity_form_lead'] ) && isset( $cart_item['_gravity_form_data'] ) ) {
        //Gravity forms generates errors and warnings.  To prevent these from conflicting with other things, we are going to disable warnings and errors.
        $err_level = error_reporting();
        error_reporting( 0 );

        $gravity_form_data = $cart_item['_gravity_form_data'];
        $form_meta         = RGFormsModel::get_form_meta( $gravity_form_data['id'] );
        $form_meta         = gf_apply_filters( array( 'gform_pre_render', $gravity_form_data['id'] ), $form_meta );
        if ( ! empty( $form_meta ) ) {

            $lead = $cart_item['_gravity_form_lead'];

            //$lead['id'] = uniqid() . time() . rand();

            $products       = $this->get_product_fields( $form_meta, $lead );
            $valid_products = array();
            foreach ( $products['products'] as $id => $product ) {
                if ( $product['quantity'] ) {
                    $valid_products[] = $id;
                }
            }

            foreach ( $form_meta['fields'] as $field ) {

                if ( ( isset( $field['inputType'] ) && $field['inputType'] == 'hiddenproduct' ) || ( isset( $field['displayOnly'] ) && $field['displayOnly'] ) || ( isset( $field->cssClass ) && strpos( $field->cssClass, 'wc-gforms-hide-from-email-and-admin' ) !== false ) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ( $field['type'] == 'product' ) {
                    if ( ! in_array( $field['id'], $valid_products ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                $value   = $this->get_lead_field_value( $lead, $field );
                $arr_var = ( is_array( $value ) ) ? implode( '', $value ) : '-';

                if ( ! empty( $value ) && ! empty( $arr_var ) ) {
                    $display_value     = GFCommon::get_lead_field_display( $field, $value, isset( $lead["currency"] ) ? $lead["currency"] : false, false );
                    $price_adjustement = false;
                    $display_value     = apply_filters( "gform_entry_field_value", $display_value, $field, $lead, $form_meta );

                    $display_text = GFCommon::get_lead_field_display( $field, $value, isset( $lead["currency"] ) ? $lead["currency"] : false, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gforms_use_label_as_value', true, $value, $field, $lead, $form_meta ) );
                    $display_text = apply_filters( "woocommerce_gforms_field_display_text", $display_text, $display_value, $field, $lead, $form_meta );

                    if ( $field['type'] == 'product' ) {
                        $prefix        = '';
                        $display_title = GFCommon::get_label( $field );
                        $display_text  = str_replace( $display_title . ',', '', $display_text );;
                        $hidden = false;
                    } else {

                        $display_title = GFCommon::get_label( $field );

                        $prefix         = '';
                        $hidden         = $field['type'] == 'hidden';
                        $display_hidden = apply_filters( "woocommerce_gforms_field_is_hidden", $hidden, $display_value, $display_title, $field, $lead, $form_meta );
                        if ( $display_hidden ) {
                            $prefix = $hidden ? '_' : '';
                        }

                        if ( ! $display_hidden && ( isset( $field->cssClass ) && strpos( $field->cssClass, 'wc-gforms-hide-from-email' ) !== false ) ) {
                            $prefix        = '_gf_email_hidden_';
                            $display_title = str_replace( '_gf_email_hidden_', '', $display_title );
                            $hidden        = true;
                        }
                    }

                    $other_data[] = array(
                        'name'    => $prefix . $display_title,
                        'display' => $display_text,
                        'value'   => $display_value,
                        'hidden'  => $hidden
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        error_reporting( $err_level );
    }

    return $other_data;
}

public function add_to_cart_validation( $valid, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( ! $valid ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check if we need a gravity form!
    $gravity_form_data = wc_gfpa()->get_gravity_form_data( $product_id );

    if ( is_array( $gravity_form_data ) && $gravity_form_data['id'] && empty( $_POST['gform_form_id'] ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['gform_form_id'] ) && is_numeric( $_POST['gform_form_id'] ) ) {
        $form_id = $_POST['gform_form_id'];

        //Gravity forms generates errors and warnings.  To prevent these from conflicting with other things, we are going to disable warnings and errors.
        $err_level = error_reporting();
        error_reporting( 0 );

        //MUST disable notifications manually.
        add_filter( 'gform_disable_user_notification_' . $form_id, array( $this, 'disable_notifications' ), 10, 3 );
        add_filter( 'gform_disable_admin_notification_' . $form_id, array(
            $this,
            'disable_notifications'
        ), 10, 3 );
        add_filter( 'gform_disable_notification_' . $form_id, array( $this, 'disable_notifications' ), 10, 3 );

        add_filter( "gform_confirmation_" . $form_id, array( $this, "disable_confirmation" ), 10, 4 );

        require_once( GFCommon::get_base_path() . "/form_display.php" );

        $_POST['gform_submit'] = $_POST['gform_old_submit'];

        GFFormDisplay::process_form( $form_id );
        $_POST['gform_old_submit'] = $_POST['gform_submit'];
        unset( $_POST['gform_submit'] );

        if ( ! GFFormDisplay::$submission[ $form_id ]['is_valid'] ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( GFFormDisplay::$submission[ $form_id ]['page_number'] != 0 ) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->delete_entry( GFFormDisplay::$submission[ $form_id ]['lead'] );
        error_reporting( $err_level );
    }

    return $valid;
}

public function order_item_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ) {
    if ( function_exists( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta' ) ) {

        if ( isset( $cart_item['_gravity_form_lead'] ) && isset( $cart_item['_gravity_form_data'] ) ) {
            $item_id = $item->get_id();
            $item->add_meta_data( '_gravity_forms_history', array(
                    '_gravity_form_lead' => $cart_item['_gravity_form_lead'],
                    '_gravity_form_data' => $cart_item['_gravity_form_data']
                )
            );

            //Gravity forms generates errors and warnings.  To prevent these from conflicting with other things, we are going to disable warnings and errors.
            $err_level = error_reporting();
            error_reporting( 0 );

            $gravity_form_data = $cart_item['_gravity_form_data'];
            $form_meta         = RGFormsModel::get_form_meta( $gravity_form_data['id'] );
            $form_meta         = gf_apply_filters( array(
                'gform_pre_render',
                $gravity_form_data['id']
            ), $form_meta );
            if ( ! empty( $form_meta ) ) {
                $lead = $cart_item['_gravity_form_lead'];
                //We reset the lead id to disable caching of the gravity form value by gravity forms.
                //This cache causes issues with multipule cart line items each with their own form.
                $lead['id'] = uniqid() . time() . rand();

                $products       = $this->get_product_fields( $form_meta, $lead );
                $valid_products = array();
                foreach ( $products['products'] as $id => $product ) {
                    if ( ! isset( $product['quantity'] ) ) {

                    } elseif ( $product['quantity'] ) {
                        $valid_products[] = $id;
                    }
                }

                foreach ( $form_meta['fields'] as $field ) {

                    if ( ( isset( $field['inputType'] ) && $field['inputType'] == 'hiddenproduct' ) || ( isset( $field['displayOnly'] ) && $field['displayOnly'] )
                         || ( isset( $field->cssClass ) && strpos( $field->cssClass, 'wc-gforms-hide-from-email-and-admin' ) ) !== false
                    ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if ( $field['type'] == 'product' ) {
                        if ( ! in_array( $field['id'], $valid_products ) ) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    $value   = $this->get_lead_field_value( $lead, $field );
                    $arr_var = ( is_array( $value ) ) ? implode( '', $value ) : '-';

                    if ( ! empty( $value ) && ! empty( $arr_var ) ) {
                        try {
                            $strip_html = true;
                            if ( $field['type'] == 'fileupload' && isset( $lead[ $field['id'] ] ) ) {
                                $strip_html = false;
                                $dv         = $lead[ $field['id'] ];
                                $files      = json_decode( $dv );

                                if ( empty( $files ) ) {
                                    $files = array( $dv );
                                }

                                $display_value = '';

                                $sep = '';
                                foreach ( $files as $file ) {
                                    $display_value .= $sep . '<a href="' . $file . '">' . $file . '</a>';
                                    $sep = ', ';
                                }
                            } else {

                                if ( $field['type'] == 'address' ) {
                                    $display_value = implode( ', ', array_filter( $value ) );
                                } else {
                                    $display_value = GFCommon::get_lead_field_display( $field, $value, isset( $lead["currency"] ) ? $lead["currency"] : false, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gforms_use_label_as_value', true, $value, $field, $lead, $form_meta ) );
                                }

                                $price_adjustement = false;
                                $display_value     = apply_filters( "gform_entry_field_value", $display_value, $field, $lead, $form_meta );
                            }

                            $display_title = GFCommon::get_label( $field );
                            $display_title = apply_filters( "woocommerce_gforms_order_meta_title", $display_title, $field, $lead, $form_meta, $item_id, $cart_item );
                            $display_value = apply_filters( "woocommerce_gforms_order_meta_value", $display_value, $field, $lead, $form_meta, $item_id, $cart_item );

                            if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gforms_strip_meta_html', $strip_html, $display_value, $field, $lead, $form_meta, $item_id, $cart_item ) ) {
                                if ( strstr( $display_value, '<li>' ) ) {
                                    $display_value = str_replace( '<li>', '', $display_value );
                                    $display_value = explode( '</li>', $display_value );
                                    $display_value = trim( strip_tags( implode( ', ', $display_value ) ) );
                                    $display_value = trim( $display_value, ',' );
                                }

                                $display_value = strip_tags( wp_kses( $display_value, '' ) );
                            }

                            $display_text  = GFCommon::get_lead_field_display( $field, $value, isset( $lead["currency"] ) ? $lead["currency"] : false, false );
                            $display_value = apply_filters( "woocommerce_gforms_field_display_text", $display_value, $display_text, $field, $lead, $form_meta );

                            $prefix         = '';
                            $hidden         = $field['type'] == 'hidden';
                            $display_hidden = apply_filters( "woocommerce_gforms_field_is_hidden", $hidden, $display_value, $display_title, $field, $lead, $form_meta );
                            if ( $display_hidden ) {
                                $prefix = $hidden ? '_' : '';
                            }

                            if ( ! $display_hidden && ( isset( $field->cssClass ) && strpos( $field->cssClass, 'wc-gforms-hide-from-email' ) !== false ) ) {
                                $prefix        = '_gf_email_hidden_';
                                $display_title = str_replace( '_gf_email_hidden_', '', $display_title );
                            }

                            if ( $field['type'] == 'product' ) {
                                $prefix        = '';
                                $display_title = GFCommon::get_label( $field );
                                $display_value = str_replace( $display_title . ',', '', $display_text );;
                            }

                            $item->add_meta_data( $prefix . $display_title, $display_value );
                        } catch ( Exception $e ) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            error_reporting( $err_level );
        }
    }
}

public function on_get_order_again_cart_item_data( $data, $item, $order ) {

    //disable validation
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', array( $this, 'add_to_cart_validation' ), 99, 3 );

    $history = isset( $item['gravity_forms_history'] ) ? maybe_unserialize( $item['gravity_forms_history'] ) : false;
    if ( ! $history ) {
        //Not sure why exactly WC strips out the leading _, let's check for it anyways
        isset( $item['_gravity_forms_history'] ) ? maybe_unserialize( $item['_gravity_forms_history'] ) : false;
    }

    if ( $history ) {
        $glead = isset( $history['_gravity_form_lead'] ) ? $history['_gravity_form_lead'] : false;
        $gdata = isset( $history['_gravity_form_data'] ) ? $history['_gravity_form_data'] : false;

        if ( $glead && $gdata ) {
            $data['_gravity_form_lead'] = $glead;
            $data['_gravity_form_data'] = $gdata;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

//Helper Functions
protected function get_product_fields( $form, $lead, $use_choice_text = false, $use_admin_label = false ) {
    $products = array();


    foreach ( $form["fields"] as $field ) {
        $id         = $field["id"];
        $lead_value = $this->get_lead_field_value( $lead, $field );

        $quantity_field = GFCommon::get_product_fields_by_type( $form, array( "quantity" ), $id );
        $quantity       = sizeof( $quantity_field ) > 0 ? $this->get_lead_field_value( $lead, $quantity_field[0] ) : 1;

        switch ( $field["type"] ) {

            case "product" :

                //ignore products that have been hidden by conditional logic
                $is_hidden = RGFormsModel::is_field_hidden( $form, $field, array(), $lead );
                if ( $is_hidden ) {
                    continue;
                }

                //if single product, get values from the multiple inputs
                if ( is_array( $lead_value ) ) {
                    $product_quantity = sizeof( $quantity_field ) == 0 && ! rgar( $field, "disableQuantity" ) ? rgget( $id . ".3", $lead_value ) : $quantity;
                    if ( empty( $product_quantity ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if ( ! rgget( $id, $products ) ) {
                        $products[ $id ] = array();
                    }

                    $products[ $id ]["name"]     = $use_admin_label && ! rgempty( "adminLabel", $field ) ? $field["adminLabel"] : $lead_value[ $id . ".1" ];
                    $products[ $id ]["price"]    = rgar( $lead_value, $id . ".2" );
                    $products[ $id ]["quantity"] = $product_quantity;
                } else if ( ! empty( $lead_value ) ) {

                    if ( empty( $quantity ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if ( ! rgar( $products, $id ) ) {
                        $products[ $id ] = array();
                    }

                    if ( $field["inputType"] == "price" ) {
                        $name  = $field["label"];
                        $price = $lead_value;
                    } else {
                        list( $name, $price ) = explode( "|", $lead_value );
                    }

                    $products[ $id ]["name"]     = ! $use_choice_text ? $name : RGFormsModel::get_choice_text( $field, $name );
                    $products[ $id ]["price"]    = $price;
                    $products[ $id ]["quantity"] = $quantity;
                    $products[ $id ]["options"]  = array();
                }

                if ( isset( $products[ $id ] ) ) {
                    $options = GFCommon::get_product_fields_by_type( $form, array( "option" ), $id );
                    foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                        $option_value = $this->get_lead_field_value( $lead, $option );
                        $option_label = empty( $option["adminLabel"] ) ? $option["label"] : $option["adminLabel"];
                        if ( is_array( $option_value ) ) {
                            foreach ( $option_value as $value ) {
                                $option_info = GFCommon::get_option_info( $value, $option, $use_choice_text );
                                if ( ! empty( $option_info ) ) {
                                    $products[ $id ]["options"][] = array(
                                        "field_label"  => rgar( $option, "label" ),
                                        "option_name"  => rgar( $option_info, "name" ),
                                        "option_label" => $option_label . ": " . rgar( $option_info, "name" ),
                                        "price"        => rgar( $option_info, "price" )
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        } else if ( ! empty( $option_value ) ) {
                            $option_info                  = GFCommon::get_option_info( $option_value, $option, $use_choice_text );
                            $products[ $id ]["options"][] = array(
                                "field_label"  => rgar( $option, "label" ),
                                "option_name"  => rgar( $option_info, "name" ),
                                "option_label" => $option_label . ": " . rgar( $option_info, "name" ),
                                "price"        => rgar( $option_info, "price" )
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    $shipping_field = GFCommon::get_fields_by_type( $form, array( "shipping" ) );
    $shipping_price = $shipping_name = "";

    if ( ! empty( $shipping_field ) && ! RGFormsModel::is_field_hidden( $form, $shipping_field[0], array(), $lead ) ) {
        $shipping_price = $this->get_lead_field_value( $lead, $shipping_field[0] );
        $shipping_name  = $shipping_field[0]["label"];
        if ( $shipping_field[0]["inputType"] != "singleshipping" ) {
            list( $shipping_method, $shipping_price ) = explode( "|", $shipping_price );
            $shipping_name = $shipping_field[0]["label"] . " ($shipping_method)";
        }
    }

    $shipping_price = GFCommon::to_number( $shipping_price );

    $product_info = array(
        "products" => $products,
        "shipping" => array( "name" => $shipping_name, "price" => $shipping_price )
    );

    $product_info = apply_filters( "gform_product_info_{$form["id"]}", apply_filters( "gform_product_info", $product_info, $form, $lead ), $form, $lead );

    return $product_info;
}

/**
 * @param $lead
 * @param $field GF_Field
 *
 * @return array|bool|mixed|string|void
 */
private function get_lead_field_value( $lead, $field ) {
    return RGFormsModel::get_lead_field_value( $lead, $field );
}

//Use a custom delete function so we don't delete files that are uploaded.
private function delete_entry( $entry ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $lead_id = $entry['id'];

    GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . "(): Deleting entry #{$lead_id}." );

    /**
     * Fires before a lead is deleted
     *
     * @param $lead_id
     *
     * @deprecated
     * @see gform_delete_entry
     */
    do_action( 'gform_delete_lead', $lead_id );

    $lead_table        = GFFormsModel::get_lead_table_name();
    $lead_notes_table  = GFFormsModel::get_lead_notes_table_name();
    $lead_detail_table = GFFormsModel::get_lead_details_table_name();


    //Delete from lead details
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM $lead_detail_table WHERE lead_id=%d", $lead_id );
    $wpdb->query( $sql );

    //Delete from lead notes
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM $lead_notes_table WHERE lead_id=%d", $lead_id );
    $wpdb->query( $sql );

    //Delete from lead meta
    gform_delete_meta( $lead_id );

    //Delete from lead
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM $lead_table WHERE id=%d", $lead_id );
    $wpdb->query( $sql );
}

/**
 * Disable gravity forms notifications for the form.
 *
 * @param type $disabled
 * @param type $form
 * @param type $lead
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function disable_notifications( $disabled, $form, $lead ) {
    return true;
}


/**
 * Disable any type of confirmations for the form.
 *
 * @param type $confirmation
 * @param type $form
 * @param type $lead
 * @param type $ajax
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function disable_confirmation( $confirmation, $form, $lead, $ajax ) {
    if ( is_array( $confirmation ) && isset( $confirmation['redirect'] ) ) {
        return $confirmation;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals', array($this, 'calculate_totals'), 10, 1);

function calculate_totals($totals){
//your code
}
```

Try using this code snippet

Comment: Can you tell me where to add this and/or what additional code I need to make this function.

I added it to Code Snippets and also tried in functions.php with no luck.

Comment: add in functions.php itself and try by printing the $totals and alter the values accordingly